# is there any difference between import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable' and import { Observable } from 'rxjs'?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When using rxjs in angular 2, 
is there any difference between 
     `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'` 
      and 
               `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is a slight difference which is the bundle size. If you aren't using tree shaking library like rollup.js which remove all unnecessary codes, your bundle will be large when importing from 'rxjs' as you are importing everything even if you are using only the Observable. On the other hand if you import from 'rxjs/Observable' you are only importing what you need and the bundle will be smaller.

> Import only what you need and patch Observable (this is useful in size-sensitive bundling scenarios)

Ref: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Comment: Besides the bundle-size the build-time will be in many cases considerably lower as well, when only importing a couple specific files vs. having the compiler go through all ~300 files in the rxjs-package alone, which will for sure add a couple of seconds + ram

Comment: Interesting point.  I am using Typescript Toolbox plugin in VS Code. It's doing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`  Is rxjs/Rx bigger than rxjs/Observable?  Should the plugin try to import the very minimum?

Comment: @techguy2000 the file size of rxjs/Rx might be less than rxjs/Observable, but what it does internally is that it imports all the other filee like Observable, map, do... and thus making your bundle size large