# Difference in importing Observable from 'rxjs/Observable' and 'rxjs'

Tags: angular, observable, reactivex

I have created an observable using `Observable.of()` by importing it from `rxjs/Observable`. But, editor was showing error. But, after so many trials I changed it from `rxjs/Observable` to `rxjs`. Then it worked fine. May I know the difference between those. I have referred some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084199/is-there-any-difference-between-import-observable-from-rxjs-observable-and) for the similar questions. But, they did not provide the complete solution. Please help me understand this.

Thanks..

Comment: `But, code was showing error` <= Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49115458/edit) and include both of these: the code **and** the error. That way we do not have to guess what transpired on your PC. **Also** include the version of `rxjs` you are using from your `package.json`.

Comment: The `But, code was showing error` means, I could see the error in the editor itself @Igor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you import 'rxjs' you're importing the entire library.  Because the library is large, this is not ideal.  However, if you import Observable separately, you'll need to also include an import for 'of' separately, such as:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

**EDIT** For Angular 6:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Thanks, @jme11 :-)

Comment: @ShadabK You're correct the syntax has changed (again :-)).  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 6 it works as

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`